# jquery not working even after delegating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jquery :

```
function Suggestions(query) {
    if (query != "") {
        $.post("suggestions/web_suggest.php", {
            text_query: query
        }, function (data) {
            $("#suggestion").html(data);
            add_css();
        });
    } else {
        remove_css();
    }
}


//..........................................................function to add styles............................................
function add_css() {
    $("#suggestion").css({
        'display': 'block'
    });
}


//......................................function to remove styles and to hide suggestion box............................................
function remove_css() {
    $("#suggestion").css({
        'display': 'none'
    });
}

function select_suggestion(value) {
    $("#stu_search_box").val(value);
    $("#suggestion").css({
        'display': 'none'
    });
}
```

html i am using :

```
<html>
<body>
<form>

</div>

<div><input type="submit" id="a" value="" onclick= /> <input type="button" id="b"  value=""/> <input type="button" id="c" value=""/></div>
<div id="browser_addin_info"> Download Our Browser plugin
for your browser to get 
easy access to our
serach engine.
</div>

<!--main body-->
<div id="main">

<!--div containing logo-->
<div id="logo_div"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Stufile" id="logo" title="Stufile"/></div>
<input type="text" id="stu_search_box" name="search_box" onkeyup="Suggestions(this.value)" />
```

buttons with id: a,b,c not working with jquery. even onclick not working, but when i remore text box and submit button of last every thing in javascript or jquery works fine.

i also used

```
$(document).on("click","#a",function(){});
```

Comment: Working in the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/859VA/1/

Comment: Any error in console???

Comment: how to check console?

Comment: old jQuery-version that doesn't support .on?

Comment: @user2845758 Press `F12` on Chrome and go to the console tab.

Comment: using latest version.

Comment: Post more js, since it works when you remove the other stuff then most likely there is an error somewhere in between

Comment: no errors on console.

Comment: Something isn't right here -> <input type="submit" id="a" value="" onclick= />  Change it to <input type="submit" id="a" value="" />

Answer (score 0):

You have not linked your jquery library. Add a script tag above your actual scripts like:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

And if you've, share the entire code for proper understanding of the problem. cause I can't seem to find the script tags anywhere.

Comment: i have added. but not mentioned